# Powershell Importing active directory groups from a CSV file fails

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have a list of groups in CSV exported from a domain to be imported onto another domain. The destionation domain already has the same OUs and so (it is a test domain). The CSV file contains group records, just like this one:

1. Name = Test group, with commas, like this
2. GroupCategory = Security
3. GroupScope = Universal
4. Path ="OU=TestFloor,OU=Prod,OU=Groups,DC=CONTOSO,DC=LO
   CAL"

I Import the CSV to an array and create the groups with a loop:

```
$Grp = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\ftest.csv" -Delimiter ";"

foreach ($g in $Grp)
{
    New-ADGroup -Name $g.Name -GroupCategory $g.GroupCategory -GroupScope $g.GroupScope -Path $g.Path
}
```

For most of the groups this works perfectly ok, but not for records like the one above, I get the following error:

```
New-ADGroup : The name provided is not a properly formed account name
```

I know that for some characters escape chars have to be used, so I modify the affected records:

1. Name = **Test group\, with commas\, like this**
2. GroupCategory = Security
3. GroupScope = Universal
4. Path ="OU=TestFloor,OU=Prod,OU=Groups,DC=CONTOSO,DC=LO
   CAL"

But the result is the same.

Any ideas?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: You made a bug]

If you want to keep the name as-is, you will need to specify the -SamAccountName switch that has the illegal characters removed.

```
New-ADGroup -Name "Test group\, with commas\, like this" -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Universal -Path "OU=TestFloor,OU=Prod,OU=Groups,DC=CONTOSO,DC=LOCAL" -SamAccountName "Test group_ with commas_ like this"
```

Comment: Which in his case like means updating whatever process is generating the CSV to include the existing SamAccountName in the export and use that.

Comment: Hey @Greg Askew, your tip solved this!. Lots of thanks.